# Access database from jBPM process

Tags: jbpm

How can I access a database from a jBPM process ? Do you think I can connect to a database using a script task, or the entry/exit action of a human task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice against using entry/exit action of a human task to store code, it can be a nightmare to figure out where did you place code since there is no visual clue when a human task has code.

You could try a script task or, as core developers recommend, you can use a custom WorkitemHandler. The latter will help in separation of code from the bpmn2 file and a custom service task will be easier to reuse in other processes instead of copy/paste. You can find the documentation here (jBPM 6) http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0.1/userguide/jBPMDomainSpecificProcesses.html