# How to create a Service Task which had CRUD capabilities with the database

Tags: java, jbpm

I want to retrieve and save data in external databases via the Service Task in JBPM process. Is it possible in jBPM?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683011/access-database-from-jbpm-process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on how to setup a [Service Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28825365/jbpm6-service-task-to-execute-java-code/28832896#28832896). You can add the necessary CRUD code into the WorkItemHandler.