# How to access MySQL database in jBoss BPM suite process

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jboss, jbpm

I am newbie in JBoss BPM Suite. What i want to achieve, is to access my MySQL database through a business process. I have already added a datasource to my application server including the jdbc driver. What i tried to do was to connect to my db by a script task. Although i got an exception ClassNameNotFound for my driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. What is the right way to connect to the db? Is there a way to do this by a service task? Or a WorkItemHandler? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683011/access-database-from-jbpm-process might help

Comment: I have already checked this question. Thanks for your tip.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to execute any complicated logic (like accessing the database) in a script task. I would also assume that your application server does not put database drivers on the classpath of its applications since it is against the whole idea of datasources. You just need to make use of the datasource you have already configured.

When it comes to the right way how to connect to the database inside your process, you will need to implement your own [work item handler](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.5.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html/ch21.html#sec.workitemhandler.overview) where you can get your data from the database. There are many different ways how you can achieve this. You can find inspiration from [JPAWorkItemHandler](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-workitems/src/main/java/org/jbpm/process/workitem/jpa/JPAWorkItemHandler.java) which will be available in version 7.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @livthomas . I know that is not the right way to do this by a script task, i just wanted to access my db. I 'll try again with a work item handler, now that I know that the driver wasn't included in the classpath. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally made the connection to my database by creating a WorkItemHandler and add it as a dependency to my BPM Suite project. After a lot of search, i think this is the best way to do it if anyone wants to access his database in a business process.